# Setting up the Ckan DataStore has compromised Ckan instance :-(

Tags: ckan

I have successfully installed the last Ckan version on a Ubuntu 14.04 server.

I have followed these instruction to install Datastore extension:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html

- plugin enabled
- database setup

and now my Ckan portal is no longer responding :(

What have i to check now?

Comment: See if there is an error message in the server log

Comment: Where is the log?

Comment: Check your server config. Depends on whether you have apache/nginx etc